# Styling the image inside the checkbox without class name

Tags: html, css, angular

[image: Screenshot]

```js
<div class="panel panel-line panel-danger">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Meb Katmanları</h3>
        <div class="panel-actions">
            <mat-slide-toggle color="warn" [(ngModel)]="allMebLayers" (change)="mebToggle()"></mat-slide-toggle>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="allMebLayers" class="panel-body" style="max-height: 70vh; overflow-y: auto">



        <mat-selection-list *ngFor="let l of legends" style="overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: hidden;">

            <mat-checkbox>
                    <td class="p-5">{{l.layerName}}</td>

                    <td class="p-5"><img [src]="l.legend.imageData"></td>
            </mat-checkbox>
        </mat-selection-list>


    </div>
</div>
```

I want to just style the image inside the checkbox. Any simple way without adding new class name ?

Comment: Its Angular 4. Sorry for that

Comment: Are you planning on adding a class name to that image manually or automatically?

Comment: I prefer without adding any new class.

Comment: Then, Julian's answer should work.  I was going to post something similar if you meant without.

Comment: It doesnt work. Can you please see the screenshot also?

Comment: I can see the screenshot.  Are you trying to change the styling based on whether or not the box is checked?  Can you provide a code sample of the styles you are trying to use on those images?

Comment: I want to put the icon images on the right to be in a distance from text that all of the icon images be below each other in straight line. At the moment none of this classes has any kind of styles.

Comment: If the right side icons be in a line like the checkbox icons on the left, it would be amazing.

Comment: Ok, you could make the td's a fixed width if you want them to line up right.  If there is a full table being generated.  You can try the .p-5 img { padding: 20px; } if you want to test whether my answer works.  There could be more wrong once the HTML is rendered that I can't tell from the image and snippet.

Comment: Thanks Joe, But "padding: 20px" doesnt work. I am not good with CSS. So i dont know how to make a line below each other.

Answer (score 2):

To style the image inside the checkbox WITHOUT a new class name, try this selector in your css document:

```
mat-checkbox img {
  /* desired CSS properties */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish the styling, you could also use:

```
.p-5 img { ... }
```

If you want to only target that image for that class and not all of the mat-checkbox img elements that could also be on the same page.